# Where should we put the cast in following situation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

where should we put cast in the following situation.

`bridgid` is `bigint` in the table.

```
CAST(ISNULL(br.bridgid, 0) as bigint)
```

or

```
ISNULL(br.bridgid, cast(0 as bigint))
```

Comment: If `bridgid` is already `bigint`, I see no functional difference between the two.

Comment: With `ISNULL(x, y)` the return type of `y` is the type of `x` so a cast is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CAST(ISNULL(br.bridgid, 0) as bigint)
```

is correct because

```
ISNULL(br.bridgid, cast(0 as bigint))
```

will always return the datatype of br.brigid even if the second argument is a higher precedence. Thanks @AlexK

Comment: ISNULL() does not care about precedence, the return type is simply the type of the first argument.

Comment: @AlexK.Understood and updated answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

@user3129097 just use :

```
ISNULL(br.bridgid, 0)
```

There is no need to cast as the bridgid is already BIGINT.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (bridgid int)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
SELECT 1 union all
SELECT null 

SELECT ISNULL(br.bridgid, 0)
FROM
    @Tbl br
```